# two events at the same time in JavaScript, click event handler not executed

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have the following event-listeners

```
element2.addEventListener("focusout", hideDropdown);
element3.addEventListener("click", addSelectedOption);
```

when I click on `element3`, only `function1` is called, but I want both to be called since clicking `element3` also means that `element2` lost focus.

When I remove the the first event listener, then the second one works. Why is this the case? and how can I get around it?

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>

<style>
    #element3 {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
</header>

<body>
<label>Multi Select</label>
<div id="element1">
    <p id="element2" contenteditable="true">Select required competencies</p>
</div>
<div id="element3" class="auto-complete-select-dropdown">
    <p>One</p>
    <p>Two</p>
    <p>Three</p>
    <p>Four</p>
</div>

<script>

    var element1 = document.getElementById("element1");
    var element2 = document.getElementById("element2");
    var element3 = document.getElementById("element3");

    element2.addEventListener("keyup", showDropdown);
    element2.addEventListener("focusout", hideDropdown);
    element3.addEventListener("click", addSelectedOption);

    function showDropdown() {
        var element = document.getElementById("element3");
        if (element.style.display != "block")
            element.style.display = "block";
    }

    function hideDropdown() {
        var element = document.getElementById("element3");
        if (element.style.display != "none")
            element.style.display = "none";
    }


    function addSelectedOption(event) {
        alert("here");
        element = event.target;
        var element1 = document.getElementById("element1");
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.textContent = element.textContent.trim();
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You'll need to show the relationship between `element1` and `element2`... like in HTML. Events travel up and down the DOM tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `focusout` event fires when the user *presses down* the mouse button on some other element. The `click` event fires when the user *releases* the mouse button over some element. So, the problem is that the `focusout` event on `element2` fires before the `click` event fires on `element3`. In the `focusout` listener, `element3`'s `display` is set to `none` - it gets hidden, which means it's unclickable a few milliseconds later when the user releases the mouse button.

Even if the user tried to click on it, the element was hidden from the `focusout` event before the `click` event could fire, so the `click` handler never runs.

One option would be to add a `mousedown` listener to `element3`, which will fire at the same time as the `focusout` event (*synchronously*, so the browser doesn't have time to repaint the page before the mousedown event gets processed):

```
element3.addEventListener("mousedown", addSelectedOption);
```

```js
var element1 = document.getElementById("element1");
var element2 = document.getElementById("element2");
var element3 = document.getElementById("element3");

element2.addEventListener("keyup", showDropdown);
element2.addEventListener("focusout", hideDropdown);
element3.addEventListener("mousedown", addSelectedOption);

function showDropdown() {
  var element = document.getElementById("element3");
  if (element.style.display != "block")
    element.style.display = "block";
}

function hideDropdown() {
  var element = document.getElementById("element3");
  if (element.style.display != "none")
    element.style.display = "none";
}


function addSelectedOption(event) {
  console.log('adding selected option');
  element = event.target;
  var element1 = document.getElementById("element1");
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.textContent = element.textContent.trim();
}
```

```css
#element3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label for="requiredCompetencies">Required Competencies</label>
<div id="element1">
  <p id="element2" contenteditable="true">Select required competencies</p>
</div>
<div id="element3" class="auto-complete-select-dropdown">
  <p>One</p>
  <p>Two</p>
  <p>Three</p>
  <p>Four</p>
</div>
```